# iterate over model field names django

Tags: python, django, models, one-to-one

I am looking to create 2 models as a one-to-one-field, the first is nothing more than T/F, the second corresponds to the fields of the first. Say if the first class has true, the second class takes the field, such that if `class 1.text == True` the next class will have `class2.text` set to something like "Hi, I am a field with text" whereas if the class1.text was False, class2.text would be empty string.

I would like to implement a form to save the second class depending on what fields the first has set to true, so I would like to iterate over the FIELD NAMES, as in if class 1 is:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    fields= OneToOneField(Data2)
    text = BooleanField
    email = BooleanField
```

and class 2 is:

```
class Data2(models.Model):
    text = BooleanField
    email = BooleanField
```

I want to set the field names for class1 into variables, and relate them like that. So in my template:

```
{% for field in Data %}
   {% if Data.field == True %}
      {{ Data2.field }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

if that makes sense. How would I accomplish this, or is there an easier way to relate all identically named fields for 2 models?

Comment: How can you have a model that represente a T/F ? Can you explain what do you want with a concrete example ? Because to my mind "Data.field == True" at your example has no sense

Comment: I've decided to implement this a completely different way that would make more sense. Sorry, disregard

Comment: While we're on the subject though, I wanted to have users determine if they want to fill out sections of a form. My friend said it'd be much easier to just leave fields they don't wanna answer blank (null=True) and check if there is anything in the field later